# Transform list of dicts, combining list items based on key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Given a list of dictionaries like:

```
history = [
  {
    "actions": [{"action": "baz", "people": ["a"]}, {"action": "qux", "people": ["d", "e"]}],
    "events": ["foo"]
  },
  {
    "actions": [{"action": "baz", "people": ["a", "b", "c"]}],
    "events": ["foo", "bar"]
  },
]
```

What is the most efficient (whilst still readable) way to get a list of dicts, where each dict is an unique `event` and the list of actions for that event have been merged based on the `action` key. For example, for the above list, the desired output is:

```
output = [
    {
      "event": "foo", 
      "actions": [
        {"action": "baz", "people": ["a", "b", "c"]}, 
        {"action": "qux", "people": ["d", "e"]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "event": "bar", 
      "actions": [
        {"action": "baz", "people": ["a", "b", "c"]}
      ]
    },
]
```

I can't change the output structure as it's being consumed by something external. I've wrote the following code which works but is very verbose and has poor readability.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def transform(history):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for item in history:
        for event in item["events"]:
            d[event] = d[event] + item["actions"]
    transformed = []
    for event, actions in d.items():
        merged_actions = {}
        for action in actions:
            name = action["action"]
            if merged_actions.get(name):
                merged_actions[name]["people"] = list(set(action["people"]) | set(merged_actions[name]["people"]))
            else:
                merged_actions[name] = {
                    "action": action["action"],
                    "people": action["people"]
                }
        transformed.append({
            "event": event,
            "actions": list(merged_actions.values())
        })
    return transformed
```

I'm only targeting python3.6+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby as gb
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in history:
  for b in i['events']:
    d[b].extend(i['actions'])

new_d = {a:[(j, list(k)) for j, k in gb(sorted(b, key=lambda x:x['action']), key=lambda x:x['action'])] for a, b in d.items()}
result = [{'event':a, 'actions':[{'action':c, 'people':list(set([i for k in b for i in k['people']]))} for c, b in d]} for a, d in new_d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[
 {'event': 'foo', 
  'actions': [
     {'action': 'baz', 'people': ['b', 'a', 'c']}, 
     {'action': 'qux', 'people': ['d', 'e']}
    ]
  }, 
 {'event': 'bar', 
   'actions': [{'action': 'baz', 'people': ['b', 'a', 'c']}]
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a less verbose answer, but maybe a bit better readable. Also it does not depend on anything else and is just standard python.

```
tmp_dict = {}
for d in history:
    for event in d["events"]:
        if event not in tmp_dict:
            tmp_dict[event] = {}
            for actions in d["actions"]:
                tmp_dict[event][actions["action"]] = actions["people"]
        else:
            for actions in d["actions"]:
                if actions["action"] in tmp_dict[event]:
                    tmp_dict[event][actions["action"]].extend(actions["people"])
                else:
                    tmp_dict[event][actions["action"]] = actions["people"]

output = [{"event": event, "actions": [{"action": ac, "people": list(set(peop))} for ac, peop in tmp_dict[event].items()]} for event in tmp_dict]

print (output)
```

Output:

```
[
   {'event': 'foo',
    'actions': [
                {'action': 'qux', 'people': ['e', 'd']},
                {'action': 'baz', 'people': ['a', 'c', 'b']}
               ]
   },
   {'event': 'bar',
    'actions': [{'action': 'baz', 'people': ['a', 'c', 'b']}]
   }
]
```